# Is there a 'greater and lesser than' comparison operator?

Tags: php, html

Is there an operator that denotes a variable as both greater and lesser than? The following code block is not valid code.

```php
if (0 < $variable < 5)
{
    etc
}
```

Comment: `if(0 < $var and $var < 5)`

Comment: can `and` and `&&` be used interchangeably?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: terrible question's title.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I'm sorry. I hope this is better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You'd want to use an "AND" operator, `&&`:

```
if ($variable > 0 && $variable < 5) {
   // bla.. bla.. bla..
}
```